# Expected argument of type "int", "App\Entity\Autoridad" given at property path "id_autoridad"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony6

while i'm working on symofny 6, i want to execute this form :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Autoridad;
use App\Entity\BalanceAnual;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\IntegerType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class BalanceAnualType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $id_partido = $options['id_partido'];
        $autoridades = $options['autoridades'];
        #dd($id_partido);
        $builder
            ->add('id_partido')
            ->add('presentacion_anual')
            ->add('ejercicio')
            ->add('dia_cierre_ejercicio')
            ->add('mes_cierre_ejercicio')
            ->add('anio_ejercicio')
            ->add('fecha_presentacion')
            ->add('aprobacion',ChoiceType::class,
                ['choices' => [
                    'SI' => 'S',
                    'NO' => 'N',
                ]])
            ->add('fecha_aprobacion')
            ->add('id_autoridad', ChoiceType::class,[
               'choices'=> $autoridades,
                'choice_label' => function ($autoridad) {
                    if(strlen($autoridad->getApellido_Nombre())> 0){
                        echo("<script>console.log('idAutoridad: " . $autoridad->getId()  ."');</script>");
                        return $autoridad->getApellido_Nombre();
                    }elseif(strlen($autoridad->getNombre())> 0){
                        echo("<script>console.log('idAutoridad: " . $autoridad->getId()  ."');</script>");
                        return $autoridad->getNombre() ." ".$autoridad->getApellido();
                    }else{
                        return $autoridad->getId();
                    }
                },
                'choice_value' =>'id'
            ])
            

            ->add('firmante_balance')
            ->add('movimentos',ChoiceType::class,
                ['choices' => [
                    'SI' => 'S',
                    'NO' => 'N',
                ]])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => BalanceAnual::class,
            'id_partido' => null,
            'autoridades' => null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

the form show all the information in the way i want, but when i want to push the data i recibe the following erro:Expected argument of type "int", "App\Entity\Autoridad" given at property path "id_autoridad".

my Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\BalanceAnualRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: BalanceAnualRepository::class)]
class BalanceAnual
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column()]
    private ?int $id_partido = null;

    #[ORM\Column()]
    private ?int $presentacion_anual = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $ejercicio = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 2)]
    private ?int $dia_cierre_ejercicio = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 2)]
    private ?int $mes_cierre_ejercicio = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 4)]
    private ?int $anio_ejercicio = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $fecha_presentacion = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 1)]
    private ?string $aprobacion = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $fecha_aprobacion = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id_autoridad = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $firmante_balance = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 1)]
    private ?string $movimentos = null;

    /*#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Autoridad::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'id_autoridad', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    private $autoridad;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Partido::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'id_partido', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    private $partido;*/
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getId_Partido(): ?int{
        return $this->id_partido;
    }

    public function setId_Partido(int $id_partido): static
    {
        $this->id_partido=$id_partido;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getIdPartido(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_partido;
    }

    public function setIdPartido(int $id_partido): static
    {
        $this->id_partido = $id_partido;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPresentacion_Anual(): ?string
    {
        return $this->presentacion_anual;
    }

    public function setPresentacion_Anual(string $presentacion_anual): static
    {
        $this->presentacion_anual = $presentacion_anual;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getPresentacionAnual(): ?string
    {
        return $this->presentacion_anual;
    }

    public function setPresentacionAnual(string $presentacion_anual): static
    {
        $this->presentacion_anual = $presentacion_anual;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEjercicio(): ?int
    {
        return $this->ejercicio;
    }

    public function setEjercicio(int $ejercicio): static
    {
        $this->ejercicio = $ejercicio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDia_Cierre_Ejercicio(): ?int
    {
        return $this->dia_cierre_ejercicio;
    }

    public function setDia_Cierre_Ejercicio(int $dia_cierre_ejercicio): static
    {
        $this->dia_cierre_ejercicio = $dia_cierre_ejercicio;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getDiaCierreEjercicio(): ?int
    {
        return $this->dia_cierre_ejercicio;
    }

    public function setDiaCierreEjercicio(int $dia_cierre_ejercicio): static
    {
        $this->dia_cierre_ejercicio = $dia_cierre_ejercicio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMes_cierre_ejercicio(): ?int
    {
        return $this->mes_cierre_ejercicio;
    }

    public function setMes_cierre_ejercicio(int $mes_cierre_ejercicio): static
    {
        $this->mes_cierre_ejercicio = $mes_cierre_ejercicio;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getMesCierreEjercicio(): ?int
    {
        return $this->mes_cierre_ejercicio;
    }

    public function setMesCierreEjercicio(int $mes_cierre_ejercicio): static
    {
        $this->mes_cierre_ejercicio = $mes_cierre_ejercicio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAnio_Ejercicio(): ?int
    {
        return $this->anio_ejercicio;
    }

    public function setAnio_Ejercicio(int $anio_ejercicio): static
    {
        $this->anio_ejercicio = $anio_ejercicio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAnioEjercicio(): ?int
    {
        return $this->anio_ejercicio;
    }

    public function setAnioEjercicio(int $anio_ejercicio): static
    {
        $this->anio_ejercicio = $anio_ejercicio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFecha_Presentacion(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->fecha_presentacion;
    }

    public function setFecha_Presentacion(\DateTimeInterface $fecha_presentacion): static
    {
        $this->fecha_presentacion = $fecha_presentacion;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFechaPresentacion(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->fecha_presentacion;
    }

    public function setFechaPresentacion(\DateTimeInterface $fecha_presentacion): static
    {
        $this->fecha_presentacion = $fecha_presentacion;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAprobacion(): ?string
    {
        return $this->aprobacion;
    }

    public function setAprobacion(string $aprobacion): static
    {
        $this->aprobacion = $aprobacion;

        return $this;
    }



    public function getFecha_Aprobacion(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->fecha_aprobacion;
    }

    public function setFecha_Aprobacion(\DateTimeInterface $fecha_aprobacion): static
    {
        $this->fecha_aprobacion = $fecha_aprobacion;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getFechaAprobacion(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->fecha_aprobacion;
    }

    public function setFechaAprobacion(\DateTimeInterface $fecha_aprobacion): static
    {
        $this->fecha_aprobacion = $fecha_aprobacion;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getId_autoridad(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_autoridad;
    }

    public function setId_autoridad(int $id_autoridad): static
    {
        $this->id_autoridad = $id_autoridad;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdAutoridad(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_autoridad;
    }

    public function setIdAutoridad(int $id_autoridad): static
    {
        $this->id_autoridad = $id_autoridad;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirmante_Balance(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firmante_balance;
    }

    public function setFirmante_Balance(string $firmante_balance): static
    {
        $this->firmante_balance = $firmante_balance;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirmanteBalance(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firmante_balance;
    }

    public function setFirmanteBalance(string $firmante_balance): static
    {
        $this->firmante_balance = $firmante_balance;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMovimentos(): ?string
    {
        return $this->movimentos;
    }

    public function setMovimentos(string $movimentos): static
    {
        $this->movimentos = $movimentos;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

my Controller:

```
#[Route('/{idPartido}/detalle/new', name: 'app_balance_anual_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function new($idPartido,Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $id_partido = intval($idPartido);
    $balanceAnual = new BalanceAnual();
    $autoridades = $entityManager->getRepository(Autoridad::class)->findBy(['id_partido' => $id_partido]);
    #dd($autoridades);
    $form = $this->createForm(BalanceAnualType::class, $balanceAnual, ['id_partido' => $idPartido, 'autoridades' => $autoridades]);
    $form->get('id_partido')->setData($idPartido);

    #dd($form->getData(), $form->getErrors());
   // print_r($request);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        //dd($balanceAnual);
        $value = $form->get('id_autoridad')->getData();
        $balanceAnual->setIdAutoridad($value);
        $entityManager->persist($balanceAnual);
            #dd($balanceAnual);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_balance_anual_index', ['idPartido' => $idPartido,], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    return $this->render('balance_anual/new.html.twig', [
        'balance_anual' => $balanceAnual,
        'idPartido' => $idPartido,
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

the two others entitys: Partido:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\PartidoRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: PartidoRepository::class)]
class Partido
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $nombre = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $numero = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 1)]
    private ?string $ambito = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $domicilio = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id_localidad = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $domicilio_partidario = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id_localidad_domicilio_partidario = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $telefono = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 1)]
    private ?string $tipo = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 2)]
    private ?string $estado = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $observaciones = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 1)]
    private ?string $libros = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 1)]
    private ?string $tipo_firma = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $fecha_presentacion = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id_localidad_ambito = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id_auto_provisorio = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $notificacion_auto_provisorio = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $publicacion_boletin_oficial = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id_auto_definitivo = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $notificacion_auto_definitivo = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id_auto_caducidad = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $observacion_caducidad = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id_expediente = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $renueva_interna = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id_extincion = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $codigo_postal = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $anio_exp_electronico = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $nro_exp_electronico = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::BIGINT)]
    private ?string $cuil_apoderado_notif = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNombre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function setNombre(string $nombre): static
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNumero(): ?int
    {
        return $this->numero;
    }

    public function setNumero(int $numero): static
    {
        $this->numero = $numero;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAmbito(): ?string
    {
        return $this->ambito;
    }

    public function setAmbito(string $ambito): static
    {
        $this->ambito = $ambito;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDomicilio(): ?string
    {
        return $this->domicilio;
    }

    public function setDomicilio(string $domicilio): static
    {
        $this->domicilio = $domicilio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdLocalidad(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_localidad;
    }
    public function getId_Localidad(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_localidad;
    }

    public function setIdLocalidad(int $id_localidad): static
    {
        $this->id_localidad = $id_localidad;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDomicilioPartidario(): ?string
    {
        return $this->domicilio_partidario;
    }

    public function setDomicilioPartidario(string $domicilio_partidario): static
    {
        $this->domicilio_partidario = $domicilio_partidario;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdLocalidadDomicilioPartidario(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_localidad_domicilio_partidario;
    }

    public function setIdLocalidadDomicilioPartidario(int $id_localidad_domicilio_partidario): static
    {
        $this->id_localidad_domicilio_partidario = $id_localidad_domicilio_partidario;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTelefono(): ?string
    {
        return $this->telefono;
    }

    public function setTelefono(string $telefono): static
    {
        $this->telefono = $telefono;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): static
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTipo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tipo;
    }

    public function setTipo(string $tipo): static
    {
        $this->tipo = $tipo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEstado(): ?string
    {
        return $this->estado;
    }

    public function setEstado(string $estado): static
    {
        $this->estado = $estado;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getObservaciones(): ?string
    {
        return $this->observaciones;
    }

    public function setObservaciones(string $observaciones): static
    {
        $this->observaciones = $observaciones;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLibros(): ?string
    {
        return $this->libros;
    }

    public function setLibros(string $libros): static
    {
        $this->libros = $libros;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTipoFirma(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tipo_firma;
    }

    public function setTipoFirma(string $tipo_firma): static
    {
        $this->tipo_firma = $tipo_firma;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFechaPresentacion(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->fecha_presentacion;
    }

    public function setFechaPresentacion(\DateTimeInterface $fecha_presentacion): static
    {
        $this->fecha_presentacion = $fecha_presentacion;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdLocalidadAmbito(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_localidad_ambito;
    }

    public function setIdLocalidadAmbito(int $id_localidad_ambito): static
    {
        $this->id_localidad_ambito = $id_localidad_ambito;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdAutoProvisorio(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_auto_provisorio;
    }

    public function setIdAutoProvisorio(int $id_auto_provisorio): static
    {
        $this->id_auto_provisorio = $id_auto_provisorio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNotificacionAutoprovisorio(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->notificacion_auto_provisorio;
    }

    public function setNotificacionAuto_provisorio(\DateTimeInterface $notificacion_auto_provisorio): static
    {
        $this->notificacion_auto_provisorio = $notificacion_auto_provisorio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPublicacionBoletinOficial(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->publicacion_boletin_oficial;
    }

    public function setPublicacionBoletinOficial(\DateTimeInterface $publicacion_boletin_oficial): static
    {
        $this->publicacion_boletin_oficial = $publicacion_boletin_oficial;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdAutoDefinitivo(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_auto_definitivo;
    }

    public function setIdAutoDefinitivo(int $id_auto_definitivo): static
    {
        $this->id_auto_definitivo = $id_auto_definitivo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNotificacionAutoDefinitivo(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->notificacion_auto_definitivo;
    }

    public function setNotificacionAutoDefinitivo(\DateTimeInterface $notificacion_auto_definitivo): static
    {
        $this->notificacion_auto_definitivo = $notificacion_auto_definitivo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdAutoCaducidad(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_auto_caducidad;
    }

    public function setIdAutoCaducidad(int $id_auto_caducidad): static
    {
        $this->id_auto_caducidad = $id_auto_caducidad;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getObservacionCaducidad(): ?string
    {
        return $this->observacion_caducidad;
    }

    public function setObservacionCaducidad(string $observacion_caducidad): static
    {
        $this->observacion_caducidad = $observacion_caducidad;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdExpediente(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_expediente;
    }

    public function setIdExpediente(int $id_expediente): static
    {
        $this->id_expediente = $id_expediente;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRenuevaInterna(): ?int
    {
        return $this->renueva_interna;
    }

    public function setRenuevaInterna(int $renueva_interna): static
    {
        $this->renueva_interna = $renueva_interna;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdExtincion(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_extincion;
    }

    public function setIdExtincion(int $id_extincion): static
    {
        $this->id_extincion = $id_extincion;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodigoPostal(): ?int
    {
        return $this->codigo_postal;
    }

    public function setCodigoPostal(int $codigo_postal): static
    {
        $this->codigo_postal = $codigo_postal;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAnioExpElectronico(): ?int
    {
        return $this->anio_exp_electronico;
    }

    public function setAnioExpElectronico(int $anio_exp_electronico): static
    {
        $this->anio_exp_electronico = $anio_exp_electronico;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNroExpElectronico(): ?int
    {
        return $this->nro_exp_electronico;
    }

    public function setNroExpElectronico(int $nro_exp_electronico): static
    {
        $this->nro_exp_electronico = $nro_exp_electronico;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCuilApoderadoNotif(): ?string
    {
        return $this->cuil_apoderado_notif;
    }

    public function setCuilApoderadoNotif(string $cuil_apoderado_notif): static
    {
        $this->cuil_apoderado_notif = $cuil_apoderado_notif;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Autoridad:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\AutoridadRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AutoridadRepository::class)]
class Autoridad
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $documento = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 1)]
    private ?string $sexo = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 10)]
    private ?string $tipo = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 200)]
    private ?string $apellido_nombre = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $apellido = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $nombre = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $domicilio = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 50)]
    private ?string $telefono = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $correo = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $fecha_alta = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $fecha_baja = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id_rol = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $orden = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id_partido = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id_eleccion_interna = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id_alianza = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getApellidoNombre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->apellido_nombre;
    }

    public function getDocumento(): ?int
    {
        return $this->documento;
    }

    public function setDocumento(int $documento): static
    {
        $this->documento = $documento;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSexo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->sexo;
    }

    public function setSexo(string $sexo): static
    {
        $this->sexo = $sexo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTipo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tipo;
    }

    public function setTipo(string $tipo): static
    {
        $this->tipo = $tipo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getApellido_Nombre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->apellido_nombre;
    }

    public function setApellido_Nombre(string $apellido_nombre): static
    {
        $this->apellido_nombre = $apellido_nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getApellido(): ?string
    {
        return $this->apellido;
    }

    public function setApellido(string $apellido): static
    {
        $this->apellido = $apellido;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNombre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function setNombre(string $nombre): static
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDomicilio(): ?string
    {
        return $this->domicilio;
    }

    public function setDomicilio(string $domicilio): static
    {
        $this->domicilio = $domicilio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTelefono(): ?string
    {
        return $this->telefono;
    }

    public function setTelefono(string $telefono): static
    {
        $this->telefono = $telefono;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCorreo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->correo;
    }

    public function setCorreo(string $correo): static
    {
        $this->correo = $correo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFechaAlta(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->fecha_alta;
    }

    public function setFechaAlta(\DateTimeInterface $fecha_alta): static
    {
        $this->fecha_alta = $fecha_alta;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFechaBaja(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->fecha_baja;
    }

    public function setFechaBaja(\DateTimeInterface $fecha_baja): static
    {
        $this->fecha_baja = $fecha_baja;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdRol(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_rol;
    }

    public function setIdRol(int $id_rol): static
    {
        $this->id_rol = $id_rol;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrden(): ?int
    {
        return $this->orden;
    }

    public function setOrden(int $orden): static
    {
        $this->orden = $orden;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdPartido(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_partido;
    }

    public function setIdPartido(int $id_partido): static
    {
        $this->id_partido = $id_partido;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdEleccionInterna(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_eleccion_interna;
    }

    public function setIdEleccionInterna(int $id_eleccion_interna): static
    {
        $this->id_eleccion_interna = $id_eleccion_interna;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdAlianza(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_alianza;
    }

    public function setIdAlianza(int $id_alianza): static
    {
        $this->id_alianza = $id_alianza;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I was trying to solve the problem by trying different options of the choiceType as well as trying through the entityType:

```
->add('id_autoridad', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Autoridad::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($id_partido) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                        ->andWhere('a.id_partido = :id_partido')
                        ->setParameter('id_partido', $id_partido);
                },
                'choice_label' => function (Autoridad $autoridad) {
                    if(strlen($autoridad->getApellido_Nombre())> 0){
                        return $autoridad->getApellido_Nombre();
                    }elseif(strlen($autoridad->getNombre())> 0){
                        return $autoridad->getNombre() ." ".$autoridad->getApellido();
                    }else{
                        return $autoridad->getId();
                    }
                },
                'choice_value' => function (?Autoridad $autoridad) {
                    if ($autoridad !== null) {
                        echo("<script>console.log('idAutoridad: " . $autoridad->getId()  ."');</script>");
                        $value = (int) $autoridad->getId();
                        return $value;
                    }
                    echo("<script>console.log(' No Entro');</script>");
                    return '';
                },
                'placeholder' => 'Selecciona un estado','required' => true,
                ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entity expect the int for $id_autoridad but in form your are using EntityType which selecting object

Comment: ->add('id_autoridad', ChoiceType::class... I am using the "ChoiceType", and by options I bring the array with the data from the controller,do you think that this array is being considered as an object of the type of that entity? Thank you for your answer